# How accurate is the file creation time on an image taken by my cell phone?

Tags: time, clock

If I have the creation time for a JPD created by a cell phone camera, how close can I assume it is to the time that the image was actually taken? I would like to use the file creation time to calculate the error in a time display that I took a picture of, but this would only work if the file creation time was within 0.5 seconds or so of the image being taken.

Comment: I will look for a cell phone forum for a better fit, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is dependent on your carrier's network clock, the time sync systems built in to your phone, and the phone's own clock. On cell phones I have used on different carriers at the same time I have routinely observed differences of up to several minutes, with no way of telling which is correct. If you're trying to detect a anomaly of half a second, I'd say your cell phone is probably not the time-piece to compare it against.

All that said:

If you take a picture of a known-good time source at several intervals and observe the time-stamps on the associated images, you could determine an offset that would allow for semi-accurate accounting.

Or, if you could place an accurate time source next to the item with the questionable clock, such that a single picture would capture both faxes simultaneously, you'd have your measurement.

However, to measure a half-second difference your clock would have to report 10ths of seconds accurately. Most of the atomic clock websites I found only resolve to full seconds, so they would not work for such a comparison. In fact, from google-searching I could not find a clock with 10th-seconds resolution, which would be the minimum necessary to make such a comparison, in the first page of results for several different queries.

But, to summarize: your cell phone is unlikely to be a reliable source, and it may take some research to find a reliable source that offers the specific features necessary to make such a comparison.

Comment: Thanks so much. I switched over to pulling up an atomic clock display on my phone (this app allows you to display to milliseconds, https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/atomic-clock/id291668819?mt=8), then using a 2nd phone to take a picture of the display next to the machine time display. This produced a much more believable estimate of the machine time display error (a few seconds) than the file creation time method (several minutes). But your idea of getting a reliable clock and taking a picture of it next to the machine time display is even better.